# Group By and Locate the Closest Number

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Data is provided at the bottom of the page.
I have 2 data frames df1 and df2.

```
df1:
ticker   Price
<chr>    <dbl>
SPY      200.00
AAPL     100.00

df2:
ticker  expiration   strike
<chr>    <dbl>       <dbl>
SPY      0621         180
SPY      0621         205
SPY      0719         180
SPY      0719         205
AAPL     0621          75
AAPL     0621         105
AAPL     0719          75
AAPL     0719         105
```

Both data frames have stock data and share a column "ticker". I would like to group df2 by 2 columns and than find the closest strike to the Price column in df1.

The output would look something like this.

```
df3 = df2 %>% group_by(ticker, expiration)%>% #which[abs(df1$Price - df2$strike) is closest to 0]

output:
ticker   expiration  strike
<chr>     <dbl>       <dbl>
SPY       0621         205
SPY       0719         205
AAPL      0621         105
AAPL      0719         105
```

Here is df1

```
structure(list(ticker = structure(2:1, .Label = c("AAPL", "SPY"
), class = "factor"), Price = c(200, 100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Here is df2

```
structure(list(ticker = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("AAPL", "SPY"), class = "factor"), expiration = c(621, 
621, 719, 719, 621, 621, 719, 719), strike = c(180, 205, 180, 
205, 75, 100, 75, 100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I am interested in @akrun data.table answer. However I am not getting the full desired output. 0719 for SPY is missing.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, Price := strike][df1, on = .(ticker, Price), roll = -Inf]
ticker expiration strike Price
1:    SPY        621    205   200
2:   AAPL        621    100   100
3:   AAPL        719    100   100
```

Comment: Note that the expected output would be 100 instead of 105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a rolling join after creating the combination with `unique` elements of 'expiration' from second dataset

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyr)
df1N <- crossing(df1, expiration = unique(df2$expiration))
setDT(df2)[, Price := strike][df1N, on = .(ticker, expiration, Price), roll = -Inf]
#    ticker expiration strike Price
#1:    SPY        621    205   200
#2:    SPY        719    205   200
#3:   AAPL        621    100   100
#4:   AAPL        719    100   100
```

---

Or do a `full_join` and then `slice` based on the `min`imum `abs`olute difference between the 'Price' and 'strike' column after grouping by 'ticker', 'expiration'

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2) %>% 
    group_by(ticker, expiration) %>% 
    slice(which.min(abs(Price - strike)))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ticker, expiration [4]
#  ticker Price expiration strike
#  <fct>  <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 AAPL     100        621    100
#2 AAPL     100        719    100
#3 SPY      200        621    205
#4 SPY      200        719    205
```

Comment: Hi akrun. I am really interested in the data.table way however I am not getting the full output. It looks like the 719 for SPY is missing. I have edited the result into my original post.

Comment: Hi akrun thanks for all the colour. However I specifically need it to select the strike that is closest to the 100 mark which would be 105 not 100.

Comment: so sorry. My mistake. Thank you so much!!! This was really troubling me.

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` answer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1) %>%
  mutate(diff = abs(strike - Price)) %>%
  group_by(ticker, expiration) %>%
  top_n(-1, wt = diff) %>%
  select(-Price, -diff)
```

Output:

```
Joining, by = "ticker"
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ticker, expiration [4]
  ticker expiration strike
  <fct>       <dbl>  <dbl>
1 SPY           621    205
2 SPY           719    205
3 AAPL          621    100
4 AAPL          719    100
```

Comment: No problem. I recommend stress-testing these solutions by setting up data where there are TWO closest values. What happens with a tie? What WOULD you like to have happen? Try to break it to make it stronger.

Comment: Nice of you to add some colour. I can add this concept to many of my other functions!

Answer (score 1):

Often times I like to use `distinct()` to select the smallest or largest values per group (or any other result of `arrange()` really). Here I'm first arranging the data by the absolute difference of `strike` and `Price`. It's very fast compared to `group_by()`. By default `distinct()` selects the first row per given combination and if we use `.keep_all = TRUE` the other columns are kept.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1) %>% 
  arrange(ticker, expiraton, abs(strike - Price)) %>% 
  distinct(ticker, expiraton, .keep_all = TRUE)
#> Joining, by = "ticker"
#>   ticker expiraton strike Price
#> 1   AAPL       621    100   100
#> 2   AAPL       719    100   100
#> 3    SPY       621    205   200
#> 4    SPY       719    205   200
```

Comment: sorry. bad edit.Thank you for your help pasi. It worked great.